# Add image from URL as an attachment in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

I know you can add an image as an attachment to an email in Rails 3 with

```
def email_image(email)
  attachments["img"] = File.read('/path to image')
  mail(:to => email)
end
```

but is there a way to attach an image from a url and not one that is saved locally? I would like to attach an image that is saved on S3 with paperclip.  Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to download the image first?

Answer (score 9):

you need to

```
require 'open-uri'
```

and then do

```
attachments["filename"] = open(url-to-image).read
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using html then you can just insert an image tag. The only issue with this is that most email clients will block the image until the user 'trusts' you.

If you want the image to be more likely to be displayed then the best thing to do is download it and embed it. However, this will add the overhead of both downloading the image and then sending it to every mail client.

Comment: Yea, I'm not trying to embed it in the email.  I'm actually sending an email to mms and would like to include it as an attachment.

Comment: In that case I'm pretty sure you will have to download the image and then send it.